# SQL Server: how can I combine the CHARINDEX, LEFT, and RIGHT functions into one expression?

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, charindex, string-function

I have the following SQL expressions, which do exactly what I need them to:

```
DECLARE @ServerName NVARCHAR(20)

SET @ServerName = RIGHT(@@SERVERNAME, LEN( @@SERVERNAME) - CHARINDEX('-', @@SERVERNAME))

SET @ServerName = LEFT(@ServerName, LEN(@ServerName) - 2)

SELECT @ServerName;
```

However, I'd like to combine the two SET expressions into one if possible. I've tried doing it on my own, but the `CHARINDEX` section throws me off. How can I combine those two so that I have one `SET` expression that does all of the work on the string at once?

Comment: Every place in your second SET statement you would need to replace @ServerName with the entire first SET statement.

Comment: Highlight this section: `RIGHT(@@SERVERNAME, LEN( @@SERVERNAME) - CHARINDEX('-', @@SERVERNAME))` and copy/paste it into the second SET statement and replace both occurrences of @ServerName

Comment: @SeanLange & Jacob H Thank you both for the suggestions, that works as intended. Can you explain why I had to copy and paste the first statement into both places in the second SET statement? Is it because that second statement is performing two functions, so it needs to perform each one on the first SET statement?

Comment: Because the result of that is stored in @ServerName so of course you have to do it twice now.

Comment: "why I had to copy and paste the first statement into both places in the second SET statement"  How else are you suppose to do it?  Your second `SET`, obviously is manipulating whatever is in `@ServerName`, which in this case the long expression in the first `SET`.

Answer (score 2):

The expression could simply be written as:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(
    @@SERVERNAME,
    CHARINDEX('-', @@SERVERNAME) + 1,
    LEN(@@SERVERNAME) - CHARINDEX('-', @@SERVERNAME) - 2
)
```

Comment: This doesn't return the same results as the original

Comment: @martin I believe it does. The code in OP seems to extract the portion after first `-`, then all characters from that substring except the last 2. The above code does exactly the same.

Comment: Ah yes. I happened to try both versions against an instance where the name contains a `-` but the portion after the `-` is longer than 20 chars. So the OP's had some extra truncation going on in the assignment to `NVARCHAR(20)` hence difference

Comment: Without sample data it is, in principle, impossible to tell if the re-written code here does what the OP's code does.

Comment: @Brian - Not really. The OP's code is fully deterministic and it is possible to derive a full specification of the behaviour of that code and refactor it.

Comment: If I had a dollar for every time test data revealed an issue with a code change that "should be identical", I could retire :)

Comment: I agree it is easy to miss edge cases where the behaviour may diverge - like the portion after the dash exceeding 20 characters but definitely not "in principle, impossible"

Answer (score 1):

The question is:

> how can I combine the CHARINDEX, LEFT, and RIGHT functions into **one
>   expression**?

The answer obviously is:

```
SET @ServerName = 
LEFT(RIGHT(@@SERVERNAME, LEN( @@SERVERNAME) - CHARINDEX('-', @@SERVERNAME)), LEN(RIGHT(@@SERVERNAME, LEN( @@SERVERNAME) - CHARINDEX('-', @@SERVERNAME))) - 2)
```

The reason why I copied/pasted the first SET expression to replace @SERVERNAME in the second SET expression is SQL Server will execute the first expression before the second one. So the string will store in the first @SERVERNAME then @SERVERNAME will be updated by the second SET expression.